# How to extend User Object in Liferay in Registration Form?

Tags: liferay, liferay-hook

I'm new with liferay.

Do you know how to create/custom registration page/action?

I need more field in registration form, like hobbies, company name, position.

I was reading the offcial documentation, liferay in action book and I am still confused about the concept.

I just created service for new table and created a hook for the custom page:

**service.xml**

```
    <entity name="UserExt" local-service="true" remote-service="true">
        <!-- PK fields -->
        <column name="userExtId" type="long" primary="true" />
        <!-- userExt fields -->
        <column name="companyId" type="long" />
        <column name="orgId" type="long" />
        <column name="hobbies" type="String" />
        <column name="createdBy" type="String" />
        <column name="createDate" type="Date" />
        <column name="updatedBy" type="String" />
        <column name="updatedDate" type="Date" />

        <!-- Order -->
        <order by="asc">
            <order-column name="userExtId" />
        </order>

        <!-- Finder methods -->
        <finder name="orgId" return-type="Collection">
            <finder-column name="orgId" />
        </finder>
    </entity>
</service-builder>
```

**create_account.jsp**

```
    <aui:input model="<%= User.class %>" name="hobbies" />
or
    <aui:input model="<%= UserExt.class %>" name="hobbies" />
```

How to connect/extend User Object between UserExt ?

Any good reference/sample project/videos ?

Crud in Liferay ?

What should I do ?

Thanks
MRizq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said you want to add more attributes to registration form you can use **Custom Field** functionality.

**Add Custom Field**

```
To add a custom field, click on the Custom Fields link in the control panel. Then choose a resource, click on the Edit link next to it and select Add Custom Field.
```

More [Info](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/lp-6-1-ugen12-custom-fields-0)